# How to remove trailing zeros from gnuplot y tics in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, axis-labels

I would like to apply a logarithmic scale on axis y with tics `10`, `1`, `0.1`, `0.01`, `0.001`, `0.0001`, and `0.00001` (without trailing zeros). Could you pleas help me how to provide this format to my GNUplot script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `xtics`, `ytics` etc. formatting where you can add or replace any tick label on the axis.

```
set logscale y
set format y '%g'
set ytics add ('.00001' 0.00001, '.0001' 0.0001, '.001' 0.001, '.01' 0.01, '.1' 0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

an alternative solution in addition to @Michael O.'s solution:

```
### custom tics
reset session

set logscale y
set ytics nomirror
do for [n in "-10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1"] {
    set ytics add (".0000000000"[1:abs(n)]."1" 10**n)
}

set logscale y2
set format y2 "10^{%T}"
set y2tics 10 nomirror

set xrange[-10:3]
plot 10**x axis x1y1, 10**x axis x1y2
### end of code
```

By the way, just in case you want get rid of the leading zero just because of saving space, the format `10^{%T}` would be even more space saving (see right axis).

[image]